# Questions about the proof of Stickelberger's theorem on discriminants

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I was going through the proof of Stickelberger's theorem about discriminants in the book 'Algebraic Number Theory' by Richard A. Mollin, and I am having some problems in understanding the proof. I will state the theorem and the proof, and I will be highly grateful if anyone can answer my questions. I have also asked this question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394785/proof-of-stickelbergers-theorem) but have not got any answers.

$\textbf{Theorem :}$ If $K$ is an algebraic number field then $\Delta_K$, the discriminant of $K$, satisfies $$\Delta_K\equiv 0,1\pmod{4}.$$

$\textbf{Proof :}$ Let $\lbrace a_1,\ldots ,a_n\rbrace\subseteq\mathfrak{O}_K$ be an integral basis for $K$ and $\sigma_1,\ldots\sigma_n :K\to \mathbb{C}$ be all the embeddings of $K$. Then we have by definition, $$\sqrt {\Delta_K}=\det([\sigma_i(a_j)])$$ and this can be written as $$\sqrt{\Delta_K}=\sum_{\pi\in A_n}\prod_{i=1}^n\sigma_i\left(a_{\pi (i)}\right)-\sum_{\pi\not\in A_n}\prod_{i=1}^n\sigma_i\left(a_{\pi (i)}\right):=P-N.$$
Now for each embedding $\sigma_i$ we have, $$\sigma_i(P+N)=P+N,\hspace{5mm}  \sigma_i(PN)=PN$$ and hence $P+N$, $PN\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Hence we have $P+N$, $PN\in\mathbb{Z}$, because $P$ and $N$ are both algebraic integers. Now using the identity $$(P-N)^2=(P+N)^2-4PN$$ it follows that $\Delta_K\equiv0,1\pmod{4}.$

$\underline{\textbf{My questions}}:$

1. How can we apply $\sigma_i$ to $P+N$ and $PN$, I mean how does it follow that $P+N$, $PN\in K$ ?

   Why is $\sigma_i(P+N)=P+N$ and $\sigma_i(PN)=PN$ ?

   From the above how does it follow that $P+N$, $PN\in\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: I sympathize with the question, but **please** tell us the source of the proof! This is not about shaming the author (many books have worse blunders), but about knowing the context and possibly the standing assumptions that might explain how things are being identified with others.

Comment: This proof originates with Schur (https://eudml.org/doc/168085).

Answer (score 9):

A bit too long for a comment, so I write it as an answer.

$(1)$ Let $L$ be the Galois closure of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
We can apply $\sigma\in Gal(L,\mathbb{Q})$ on $P+N$ and $PN$, which lie in $L$.

$(2)$ Since either $\sigma(P)=P$ and $\sigma(N)=N$ or $\sigma(P)=N$ and
$\sigma(N)=P$, it always follows that $\sigma(P+N)=P+N$ and $\sigma(PN)=PN$, for
$\sigma\in Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$, where $L$ is the Galois closure of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$(3)$ So $P+N$ and $PN$ are fixed under elements of $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})$, hence in $\mathbb{Q}$ by definition.

EDIT: Look here for more details (page 12): web.mit.edu/~holden1/www/math/ant.pdf

Comment: Can you please tell how do you prove your first and second claim ?

Comment: I am not convinced of **(1)**. (The Holden proof sidesteps this completely by only using that $P$ and $N$ lie in $K^{\mathrm{gal}}$.

Comment: @darij: sorry, you are right.

Comment: Just a note for myself: given any $\tau \in Gal(L / \Bbb Q)$, the set $\{\tau \circ \sigma_i\}_i$ is a permutation of the $\{\sigma_i\}$, so that we have the dichotomy in (2).

Answer (score 5):

This is just a clarification of Dietrich Burde's remarks taken from Schur's original proof. Let $K$ be generated by a root $\beta$ of a monic polynomial $f \in {\mathbb Z}[x]$. Then each $\alpha_i$ is a rational polynomial in $\beta$, and each $\sigma_j$ permutes the roots of $f$; thus we may apply the $\sigma_j$ to $P$ and $N$. Since $P+N$ and $PN$ are symmetric functions of these roots (even permutations fix $P$ and $N$, odd permutations switch them), these expressions are rational algebraic integers, i.e., ordinary integers.